# How many Base or MetaData instances do you need in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm currently reading the docs on SQLAlchemy for use in Flask and one thing that is very unclear to me is how many instances of certain SQLAlchemy objects (such as `Base` or `MetaData`) I need?

For example, the ORM documentation here (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html) shows this example:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    ...
    ...
```

So now, do I need an instance of `Base` per ORM class? Or can I declare a single instance of `Base` somewhere (such as in `__init__.py`) and just re-use it? If I can declare a single instance and just re-use it, is it thread-safe from an initialisation point of view or do I need to make sure that some or all of the ORM related initialisation happens once at startup?

Likewise, a similar situation with `MetaData`:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey

metadata = MetaData()
users = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    Column('name', String),
    Column('fullname', String))
```

Now, if I were to declare an addresses `Table` just below users (as in the example in the docs) I can see how that would probably be fine as execution would occur sequentially. But what if I put addresses in another module? Would I then need to create a new instance of `MetaData` for that module or could I again declare a single instance in the `__init.py__` and re-use it?

I find myself asking this question over and over again. I'm also trying to work out whether having multiple `Base` or `MetaData` objects is a problem?

I'm relatively new to large scale Python development (I've done a lot of single-threaded scripting in it), so perhaps my understanding around scoping and threading is somewhat lacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one instance of Base in a flask project. If you use flask-sqlalchemy then you can directly use **Model** from SQLAlchemy instance:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    pass
```

Using Flask-SQLAlchemy you will have paging and some useful methods like get_or_404 available, it will save your time later.